# php mysql query whitin While loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a Mysql table which is use in php, first I use while loop to fetched the rows that as below

```
$q1 = "SELECT * FROM same_table WHERE `t_type`=1 AND `status`=0 AND `accept`='0'";

while($row1 = $q1->fetch_assoc()){

    ...table to output records

    echo '<tr>
          <td>$row1['col1']</td>
          <td>$row1['col2']</td>
          </tr>';
}
```

this will come out necessary records successfully.

secondly, there is another row with different purpose located under each of the above query row if the condition is true, with same table (within while loop),

```
while($row1 = $q1->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<tr>
          <td>$row1['col1']</td>
          <td>$row1['col2']</td>
          </tr>';

    $q2 = "SELECT * FROM same_table WHERE `t_type`=1 AND `status`=0 AND `bonus_accept`='0'";

    $row2 = $q2->fetch_assoc();

    if(($row2['col3'] == true){
        echo '<tr>
              <td>$row2['col1']</td>
              <td>$row2['col2']</td>
              </tr>';
    }

}
```

so far the $q2 rows is show but always repeat the first record's data only even there is several row for $q1. if the data for `$row2['col1']` is 100, the rest all show 100.

Please kindly help.

Comment: you have not' execute the query.

Comment: @Satish Sharma, yes it does in my real code, I just want to simplify the codes above

Comment: what's your actual need, your question is not understandable completely.